# Sequelize and module.exports

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to nodejs and Sequelize and have been having an issue that I cannot figure out how to get over. I want to use a connection I created and exported it to a module.

Like this:

```
const dotEnv        = require('dotenv');
const Sequelize     = require('sequelize');

dotEnv.config();

module.exports.connection = async () => {
    try{
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_DATABASE, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: process.env.DB_PORT,
            dialect: 'mysql',
            logging: false,
            define: {
                charset: 'utf8',
                collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
            },
        });
        await sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw error;
        });
    }catch(error){
        throw error;
    }
}
```

I then have another file where I want to use it that looks like this

```
const Sequelize     = require('sequelize');
const { connection }= require('../database');

const accountModel = connection.define('accounts', {
  // attributes
  id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true
  },
  password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      //is: /^[0-9a-f]{64}$/i
  },
  permission: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
  },
  discount: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
});
module.exports = connection.model('accounts', accountModel);
```

The problem is that I get told that: TypeError: connection.define is not a function,

The connection works, the database is running, everything else works
And last if I do it like this, it works too:

```
const dotEnv        = require('dotenv');
const Sequelize     = require('sequelize');

dotEnv.config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_DATABASE, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
    define: {
        charset: 'utf8',
        collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
    },
});

const accountModel = sequelize.define('accounts', {
  // attributes
  id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true
  },
  password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      //is: /^[0-9a-f]{64}$/i
  },
  permission: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
  },
  discount: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
});
module.exports = sequelize.model('accounts', accountModel);
```

I am really not sure why the module one does not work but the direct method does. I have tried to search Google and Stack Overflow for a solution.

Comment: @DenisTsoi: we should try to avoid asking for repos if we can help it. The point of Stack Overflow is to produce answerable problems within the question post itself, so that if a repo/link dies, the question will still be understandable for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your first approach is that you exported first of all an `async function` and not the `Sequelize instance` (as it is in your second example) and secondly the function itself is not returning anything. That's why there is no `connection.define()` function when you require that in another file.

try this in `database.js` and it should work:

```
module.exports.connection = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_DATABASE, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: process.env.DB_PORT,
            dialect: 'mysql',
            logging: false,
            define: {
                charset: 'utf8',
                collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
            },
        });
```

You can do all that `authenticate()` and `try {} catch (error) {}` somewhere else for example in your very first `js` file where you starting the server by requiring the same `database.js` file. But for the model definitions it's important that you are exporting just the `new Sequelize()` instance to them to be able to use `define()`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.  In the connections file you export the function then in the accountModel file you import and invoke the function.

connection.js:

```
exports.connection= async function() { // Stuff here }
```

accountModel.js:

```
const { connection }= require('../database');
let connection = await connection.connection();
```